# Running my own dynamic DNS service

Tags: subdomain, dynamic-dns

I am planning to build my own little dynamic DNS service for my home server. I have a domain hosted by a provider who provides a web interface to create and edit nameserver record. This domain has an A record 'example.com' which points to a root server with a static IP which is hosted by another provider.

What I want to do is to run a nameserver on this server which should resolve the dynamic IP of my internet access at home to 'home.example.com'. This nameserver will be updated remotely if the IP changes.

For my understanding I have to create a NS record 'home.example.com' for my domain pointing to 'example.com'. If now the hostname 'home.example.com' should be resolved, the nameserver at my server will be asked.

My question: will this work this way or did I missed something?

Comment: Ae you using `bind`? Can you add the config you've built so far?

Comment: I have not set up anything yet. First I want the be clear about the prerequisits. Setting up a nameserver (whatever I will use, bind seems a bit bloated to me) should not be the problem.

Comment: You need a server (can be done in `perl` e.g.) that simply returns an ip-address for a hostname. You don't want to resolve anything at that stage.

Comment: Just to be clear, you *do* have a static ip to host the nameserver on, correct?

Comment: Right, the root server which should run the nameserver has a static IP (to which may domain 'example.com' resolves).

Comment: https://github.com/lordloh/dynDnsEP - is my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question by my own:

For my domain 'example.com' exists an A record with the IP of my server. I have created a NS record for `home.example.com` with target `example.com`.

For a simple test if this works I used `dnsmasq`. On my server, I created a new file `test_hosts` with the following content:

```
1.2.3.4 home.example.com
```

Than I started `dnsmasq` with the following parameters on my server:

`dnsmasq --no-hosts --addn-hosts=test_hosts --no-daemon --log-queries --no-resolv`

If I now execute `nslookup home.example.com` from any computer I will get the following result:

```
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   home.example.com
Address: 1.2.3.4
```

For the final configuration of a self-hosted dynamic DNS service one can use `bind` on the server side and `nsupdate` on the client side. There are more than one manual which will shown how to install such a setup.